# Wordpress links aren't displayed correctly

Tags: wordpress, http, url, hyperlink

A friend of mine has a problem with his wordpress blog. When you watch the source code of the website in your browser you can find some links which aren't displayed correctly.

```
<a title="Fanpage" href="//www.facebook.com/#%21/pages/Global-Recordsde/134054559993963" target="_blank">
```

Instead of a http://... link there're just two slashes (e.g.: href="//www.facebook.com/#%21/pages/Global-Recordsde/134054559993963"). I couldn't find an error, although he removed all installed plugins and rewatched the source code. Does someone have an idea where the error could be?

You can watch into the source code on the following site:
http://www.global-records.de/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong here; they are protocol relative URLs. They are typically used for linking to third party resources from a page that may be served over HTTP or HTTPS. More info: http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/